How to fix this confusing error: failed:missing ) after argument list
With this code:
Store text | xpath=(//button[contains(@type,'button')])[4] | ots
execute script | return ${ots}.includes("Mis OT's"); | otsmod
if | ${otsmod} == true
echo | Mis OT's OK

I’m getting this error:

Error:executeScript on return ${ots}.includes("Mis OT's"); with value otsmod  Failed:missing ) after argument list

The error message is easy enough to understand, how does it apply here?
I guess it’s related to the single-quote as this similar example works:
store text | xpath=(//button[contains(@type,'button')])[3] | agen
execute script | return ${agen}.includes("Agendamientos"); | agend
if | ${agend} == true
echo | Agendamientos OK

How can I avoid this error?
